# Checking for Insecure items on https

Tags: video, https, embed, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have a vimeo video embedded on the home page of my website that uses https. I ran a test using Fiddler2 to see if there were any insecure items on the page and I received the following error message:

The remote server (player.vimeo.com) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Does this indicate the embedded video is an insecure element?

Answer (score 0):

This post can be helpful for you.
In your case I think that the "error" comes from the fact that the video is on something like https://server.vimeo.com and your site is https://my.site.com
you notice that the 2 domaines are difference and that injecting video from the second domain can be seen as a problem.
An other option could be that vimeo is redirecting you to one of its server IP address and thus raises the error.
In any case, the video is not insecure.

Comment: So the key phrase there is "can be seen as a problem". Is this something that search engines could be seeing as a problem as well? Right now our homepage is not being index by any search engine.

Comment: How long did you set your honepage for indexing ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "How long did you set your homepage for indexing"

Comment: It takes time to get indexed, especially the first time. This can go up to few weeks in some cases.